# htaccess - creating exception for the subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, subdomain

I have problem with htaccess subdomain exception.

I've added the code below to create an exception for the uae.example.it subdomain which is a password protected directory.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !uae\.example\.it
```

However my browser is not prompting me for username and password and showing me:

> Forbidden
>   "You don't have permission to access / on this server. Additionally, a
>   404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an
>   ErrorDocument to handle the request."

This is my whole htaccess file. I believe this is a .htaccess related issue. Any suggestions?

```
Options -Indexes  
IndexIgnore *

RewriteEngine on

#########################################
# RIMUOVO WWW                           #
#########################################

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !uae\.example\.it
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.it$ [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.it/$1 [R=301,L]


#########################################
# REDIRECT A SITO WEB                   #
#########################################

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/abc0000/(.*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/abc2015/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /abc2015/$1 [NC,L]


#########################################
# LANG                                  #
#########################################

#RewriteRule ^abc2015/it/(.*) abc2015/$1 [L]
#RewriteRule ^abc2015/en/(.*) abc2015/$1 [L]

#########################################
# SEO FRIENDLY URL                      #
#########################################

#RewriteRule ^abc2015/r-(.*)$ abc2015/index_exec.php?cmd=seo&fn=$1 [NC,L]
#RewriteRule ^abc2015/p-(.*)$ abc2015/$1.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^abc2015/en/$ abc2015/index.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^abc2015/it/$ abc2015/index.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^abc2015/en/our-company$ abc2015/company.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^abc2015/it/la-nostra-azienda$ abc2015/company.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^abc2015/en/sectors$ abc2015/sectors.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^abc2015/it/settori$ abc2015/sectors.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^abc2015/en/expertise$ abc2015/expertise.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^abc2015/it/competenze$ abc2015/expertise.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^abc2015/en/projects/(.*)$ abc2015/projects.php?fn=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^abc2015/it/progetti/(.*)$ abc2015/projects.php?fn=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^abc2015/en/project/(.*)$ abc2015/project.php?fn=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^abc2015/it/progetto/(.*)$ abc2015/project.php?fn=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^abc2015/en/contacts$ abc2015/contacts.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^abc2015/it/contatti$ abc2015/contacts.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^abc2015/en/privacy-policy$ abc2015/terms.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^abc2015/it/privacy-policy$ abc2015/terms.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^abc2015/en/careers$ abc2015/careers.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^abc2015/it/lavora-con-noi$ abc2015/careers.php [NC,L]


#########################################
# ERROR PAGES                           #
#########################################

#ErrorDocument 400 /abc2015/error.php?error=400
#ErrorDocument 401 /abc2015/error.php?error=401
#ErrorDocument 403 /abc2015/error.php?error=403
#ErrorDocument 404 /abc2015/error.php?error=404
#ErrorDocument 500 /abc2015/error.php?error=500

###
# SecFilterEngine Off
# SecFilterScanPOST Off
###
```

Answer (score 0):

`RewriteCond` is only for the next `RewriteRule`.
If you do not want to use other rules with `uae.example.it` add at the begining:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^uae\.example\.it$
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

This means: do nothing else

Comment: This removed the exception for the subdomain, now browser redirects me to "abc2015/uae". @Croises

Comment: Did you try with other browser (problem with cache). Because if it's the first rule, no redirection after for this subdomain